# When would you use AffineTransform getScaleX()?

Tags: java, matrix, awt, affinetransform

Is there a legitimate use case for `AffineTransform.getScaleX()` and family?

It returns the m00 or the top left corner element of the transform matrix and that is pretty useless for determining the scaling the matrix does. Consider for example a trivial 90 degree rotation matrix and both `getScaleX()` and `getScaleY()` return 0.

I would never use this call as it is confusing to the code reader who may not be familiar with the fact that it does not return scaling in a meaningful way, much better to `getMatrix(m)` and then access the m[0], because most people likely to read code that uses transformations are familiar with matrix math.

There must be a use case for this, but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the notion of the x scaling factor is quite meaningless in the general case. It is only relevant for the special case of scaling matrixes. i.E. those for which `getType` returns `TYPE_GENERAL_SCALE` or `TYPE_UNIFORM_SCALE`. (A translation could be added, too) In other cases, `getScaleX` is "correct" in the sense that it does what the docs say, but usesless and misleading regarding its name. Analogous reasoning applies to `getShearX`, which only makes senses in context of shearing matrixes. `getTranslateX` is a bit different, since one could argue that this is where the origin gets translated to, regardless of all other transformations the matrix implies.

Comment: Basically that is the answer I was fishing for, but I'll wait some before I accept it, in case someone knows/comes up with something better.